# Factory function not returning data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-factory

I have an angularjs factory to get data via `$http.get()`:

```
'use strict';
app.factory('apiService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var apiService = {};
    apiService.urlBase = 'http://localhost:1337/api/';
    apiService.get = function (urlExtension) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: apiService.urlBase + urlExtension
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            return response.data;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }

    return apiService;
}]);
```

The problem is, that it always returns `undefined` when i call the method apiService.get(); in a Controller. When I log the response data in the factory, it display the right data. The apiService.urlBase variable is always filled in my controller.

Do you guys have any suggestions or am I doing something wrong? Maybe it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved the problem. I just passed a callback function via parameter for my get() function.

```
'use strict';
app.factory('apiService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var apiService = {};
    apiService.urlBase = 'http://localhost:1337/api/';
    apiService.get = function (urlExtension, callback) {
        var data = {};

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: apiService.urlBase + urlExtension
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            data = response.data;
            callback(data);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });

        return data;
    }

    return apiService;
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the promise that is returned by `$http`. Add `return` before `$http`

Comment: yeah okay, this kind of works, but now i get a $$state object, do you have any suggestions on how to handle that?